# Replace the last letter of a file name with the corresponding alphabet number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a **renamer application** which is doing various stuff using **Javascript**. Application gives me this **function** by default `function(index, item) { }` and I have to write my code in there, which could looks like this `function(index, item) {return item.newBasename...etc}`.

What I want to do is to **replace** the **last letter** of a **filename**, to its corresponding **alphabet number**. For example from "Filename **AA**" to "Filename **A1**".

Based on this example below, how can I do this?

```
function(index, item) {
    return item.newBasename.replace(???);
}
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: `replace every single letter, which is at the last position of a filename` - this doesn't make sense. There can be only one letter in the _"last position"_.

Comment: @fubar: I mean every letter from "A" to "Z"!!!

Comment: please add some examples and the code you tried.

Comment: Edit your question to show some before and after examples.

Comment: Excuse me guys but I can't add any other example than the existing one because in this particular case, I have no idea what should I do... Not even how to start!!!

Comment: @SimonetosTheGreek, I meant an example of the filename input value before replacement and the expected output value. That you must surely know to be able to solve the problem.

Comment: @fubar: I added an example of the filename input and expected output value at my initial question...

Comment: Great, then see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution...

```
function(index, item) {
    str=item.newBasename;
    num=str.toUpperCase().slice(-1).charCodeAt(0) - 64;
    if (num>0 && num < 27) str = str.slice(0, str.length - 1) + num;
    return str; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.prototype.replace` with a regular expression to match the last letter of the filename, and a function to find the corresponding letter position in the alphabet.

For example:

```js
const basename = 'hello-world'.replace(/([a-z])$/i, l => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.indexOf(l.toLowerCase()) + 1);

console.log(basename);
```

Comment: I can't make it work... I am doing this `function(index, item) {return item.newBasename.replace(/([a-z])$/i, l => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.indexOf(l.toLowerCase()) + 1);}` but nothing. Application says "Got Errors", just that!!! Did I have any syntax error or something?

Comment: What is the error? Look at the console, or the error log.

Comment: This application does not provide error log!!! I am talking about "Advanced Renamer".